# Django - TypeError at /statements/ int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'AnonymousUser'

Tags: python, django, typeerror

In my Django project, I have a **statement** app which just stores the statements of the registered users. I was experimenting with it to learn Django and at some point, I asked myself how to show only the statements of the current user. So, I filtered the queryset based on the current user and then I have got this error message (see title), when I wanted to see the statements.

My views.py:

```
from statements.models import Statement
from statements.serializers import StatementSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import permissions
from statements.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.response import Response

from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication



@api_view(['GET'])
def api_root(request, format=None):
    return Response({'links':{
        'users': reverse('user-list', request=request, format=format),
        'statements': reverse('statement-list', request=request, format=format)
    }})


class StatementList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    #queryset = Statement.objects.all()      <--- with this, everything was fine but I wanted to get only the statements of the current user
    serializer_class = StatementSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    # I've overridden this method so that only the statements of the current user should be displayed (BUT this caused the error) 
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        return Statement.objects.filter(owner=user)


    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)

        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({'statements': serializer.data})

class StatementDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Statement.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatementSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)


class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class UserDetail(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

My models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Statement(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='statements', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

My serializers.py:

```
class StatementSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')

    class Meta:
        model = Statement
        fields = ('url','id', 'text', 'owner')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    statements = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(many=True, view_name='statement-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'statements')
```

So, I also read the other stackoverflow posts regarding this type error, but they were not helpful.

Comment: Please post the full traceback in the question, and avoid posting the exception in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in StatementList View.
If the request is unauthenticated the default value of `request.user` is an instance of `django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser`.

So, you can check if the user is authenticated before doing `Statement.objects.filter(owner=user)` query.

```
# views.py
class StatementList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    #queryset = Statement.objects.all()      <--- with this, everything was fine but I wanted to get only the statements of the current user
    serializer_class = StatementSerializer
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

    # I've overridden this method so that only the statements of the current user should be displayed (BUT this caused the error) 
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        # check if the user is authenticated
        if user.is_authenticated():
            return Statement.objects.filter(owner=user)
        return Statement.objects.none()

# END
```

Or you can change the `permission_classes` to `permissions.IsAuthenticated`, it will make sure that only authenticated user can access the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in settings.py
**DEBUG = True**